# Patterns, Series, and Chaos

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition, chaos-theory

What are good books for studying patterns, and other supporting topics like different series types manipulation...etc. which concentrates on the conceptual side that you may read it in your leisure time with little or no mathematical intervention along side with those books which connects the concepts with mathematical models. And if there are advanced ones to help me study chaos theory up ahead?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/How-Make-Sewing-Patterns-second/dp/0932538215

Comment: So, you want books about patterns, and books about different types of manipulation of series, and both with no mathematics (so, why are you asking on a mathematics website?), and you want advanced books on chaos theory. What a jumble!

Comment: I said those of pure concepts and analogy along side with those of mathematical manipulation. Sorry if I am not clear in the question!